# Windows 10 thinks VB Script is a virus

Tags: vbscript

I created a PHP web form that creates a vbscript which will download a specific file and install it. Everything works great and the project is done but now Windows 10 is automatically deleting the file once it's downloaded. Windows 10 thinks its a virus.

There's no malicious code but I do have the following code so that it runs as an admin:

```
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
    , """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ /elevate", "", "runas", 1
 WScript.Quit
End If
```

Is there anything I can do so that Windows 10 doesn't think a VBscript is a virus?

Thanks,

Comment: Is it possible to sign VBScipt file somehow, using your developer code signing certificate? Otherwise it looks very like malicious code, I would not trust it either :)

Comment: Don’t download VBScript through a web form would be a good start.

Comment: Even if you're the one creating the web form? There's no malicious code. Its a script to automate a task to save time. I will look into signing a cert.

Comment: Downloading any code be it malicious or not is a huge no no from a web form, not surprised Windows AV blocked it.

Comment: Maybe adding an exclusion/whitelist folder and download-running from there would work for your specific use-case? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028485/windows-10-add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security